# Does R include an efficient implementation of sets?

Tags: r, set, time-complexity

Is there an efficient implementation of the set data structure in R?

In C++ I would use an `std::set` (which is implemented using red-black trees), in Python a `set` (which is implemented using hash tables), but I am not sure what I should use in R.

I have found this [link](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sets.html), which describes some set operations, like `union()` and `intersection()`, that you can perform on vectors. So, I guess that since vectors are involved, the complexities would not be logarithmic, as you could have using the data structures mentioned above.

Fun fact, note how in this case the name of the language does not help, searching "r set" one finds many results concerning $\mathbb{R}$, and not the programming language :D

Comment: Nothing built in, but there are various packages such as: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sets/sets.pdf

Comment: `s <- new.env(hash=TRUE)` is the built-in way to get a performant hash table.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but you might be interested into [this research](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2018/RJ-2018-037/RJ-2018-037.pdf) comparing a bunch of different collection types